# Open parenthesis is missing in the variable when passing test data using python Selenium test automation.2 robotframework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

When we are passing test data for automation tests using python Robot framework using a variable as below:

```
${Variable Name}   US West (Oregon) | us-west-2
```

The value of the variable supposed to be passed as is, but it is returning as   `US West Oregon) | us-west-2`
So the open paranthesis '(' is missing in the variable. This behaviour is occuring only when it is run in Linux environment, and the variable is passed normally while executing our tests in Linux.

To give more insight, the sendkeys passed using variable in two OS as given below:

in Windows : `US West (Oregon) | us-west-2<br>`

in LInux : `US West Oregon) | us-west-2`

Comment: Have you verified via the log that the variable is set to the proper value before you call the keyword? What keyword are you calling that is modifying the value?

Comment: Yes, We have set the variable properly and in the Log file its showing correctly , but while passing the variable value inside the search text field by selenium robot framework the parenthesis is missing.

We are using below robot framework keyword and the variable declared as shown below.

${REGION NAME} = US West (Oregon) | us-west-2

Click Element    css=#s2id_region > .select2-choice
Input Text    css=#select2-drop .select2-input    ${REGION NAME}